# SSRS - XML datasource - Return result

Tags: sql, xml, sharepoint, reporting-services

Wondering if anyone can help - been google-ing aaaaaall morning with no results.

I've created a dataset in SQL Server Report Builder that gets my Sharepoint userprofile (datasource = xml web service SharePoint UserProfileService). The dataset query results shows my info - columns are f.ex.

**Name            - type         -       Value**

Title  -             xsd:string     -      Specialist

Department    -      xsd:string      -     Accounting

WorkPhone      -     xsd:string      -     555-55555

etc.

Now, I want the query to only return the **Value column **, where Name equals Department....
So the result of the dataset looks like this

**Value**

Accounting

If anyone can help please :)

**Update**
This is the Return result xml node I only want to return

```
 <PropertyData>
 <IsPrivacyChanged>false</IsPrivacyChanged>
 <IsValueChanged>false</IsValueChanged>
 <Name>Department</Name>
 <Privacy>Public</Privacy>
<Values>
<ValueData>
 <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Accounting</Value>
 </ValueData>

     </Values> 
</PropertyData>
```

I´m guessing I have to do something like

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">GetUserProfileByNameResponse{}/GetUserProfileByNameResult{}/PropertyData{**?????**}/</ElementPath>
```

Comment: I dont get it - why bother? Cant you just use the columns you want in your SSRS page design and ignore the rest?

Comment: because I want to use the result as a parameter in another dataset. I only need the department data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a "Microsoft SharePoint List" as Connection type in the data source, you can still select the "User Information List" and create a filter for that in the dataset properties?